# Mapping plots with multiple parameter values

Tags: plotting, map

The model I am trying to copy is this(not really necessary to look at it):

https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/plot-themes/table-of-plots.html

but my problem is slightly different and I am trying to adapt it. (ignoring the formatting).

I have tried this:

```
function[a_,z_]=azr
Clear[parameters1]
parameters1 := Table[{i, j}, {i, 1.3, 5.3}, {j, {1, 10, 20, 30, 40}}]
Clear[parameters2]
parameters2 := MapThread[function @@ # &, {#}] & /@ Transpose[parameters1]

Map[Plot[#, {r, 0, 1.2}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 150, 
PlotRange -> {0, 40}] &, parameters2, {2}]
```

The issue is that when I plot, the incorrect values get mapped. For instance, there is no graph with the values a=5.3 and z=40 that I can see. I believe the first row of graphs is correct but then the latter ones are not.

I think everything up to parameters 2 is correct but the last line is what is where the problem is.

Note: that the function is just an example, for my application I am using something different, but I am still mapping values for two of the parameters and using the third one for the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm seeing all the graphs in the expected order, including the one you mention (which comes last).  What you have is equivalent to the following

```
Clear[parameters2, f, a, z, r]
f[a_, z_, r_] = a*z*r
parameters2 = Outer[f[#1, #2, r] &, {1, 10, 20, 30, 40}, 0.3 + Range[5]]
options = {AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 100, PlotRange -> {0, 40}}
Grid@Map[Plot[#, {r, 0, 1.2}, Evaluate@options] &, parameters2, {2}]
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the best command but something isn't right. When i check out the last plot using Manipulate[plot[xyr,{r,0,1.2}],{a,5.3},{z,40}]. I get a different graph. How is this possible? Are these not equivalent? @Alan

Comment: Sorry meant to say Manipulate[plot[azr,{r,0,1.2}],{a,5.3},{z,40}] @Alan

Comment: Omg sorry another mess up! Manipulate[Plot[a*z*r,{r,0,1.2}],{a,5.3},{z,40}]. Clearly this graph is different from the last graph? Why is this happening @Alan

Comment: @Dio They are the same, except that in this new plot you did not set `PlotRange`, so instead of `{0,40}` you got the full range.

Answer (score 3):

Adding plot labels so you can see which graph corresponds to which parameter values:

```
ClearAll[fObs,r];
fObs = Flatten[
   Table[{r*i*j, i, j}, {j, {1, 10, 20, 30, 40}}, {i, 1.3, 5.3}], 1];
Grid@Partition[
  Map[Plot[#[[1]], {r, 0, 1.2}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 100, 
     PlotRange -> {0, 40}, 
     PlotLabel -> ("a: " <> ToString[#[[2]] ] <> ", z: " <> 
        ToString[#[[3]] ]) ] &, fObs], 
      5]
```

[image: Grid Output]

Comment: Repeating comment here: Not sure if this is the best command but something isn't right. When i check out the last plot using Manipulate[Plot[a*z*r,{r,0,1.2}],{a,5.3},{z,40}]. I get a different graph. How is this possible? Are these not equivalent?